# How do I view the call stack of an executable?

Tags: memory

Basically I'm trying to edit memory (replace branch with a nop so the executable can't branch to auth function). I've done successful reverse engineering on gaming consoles, but I don't really know where to start on PC. WinDbg? VS2010 debugger? I would really appreciate any tips or pointers, thanks :)

Comment: What you are looking for is not suitable for here but rather tutorial websites and/or youtube videos.

Answer (score 2):

I think that what you are looking for is a disassembler for `PE` format files (Windows Portable Executable format). The call stack itself has nothing to do with it - you need to modify the flow of a program.

`Windbg` and `X64dbg` are great debugging tools for PC, as well as `IDA` and `Ghidra` for static analysis and patching.